# Looking for a collection of alternate words - not a thesaurus

Tags: vocabulary, parts-of-speech, derivation, derivational-morphology

I'm looking for a database of alternate words, not like a thesarus, but as they're listed in a dictionary. E.G. not "terrible" => "bad, awful" etc but "terrible" => "terribly".

Is there a specific term I should be looking for for this sort of list? All my googling is just bringing back thesauri.

Comment: Do you mean "related words"? *Terribly* is not an alternate for *terrible* in most senses, in most dialects.

Comment: Yes, that's more accurate - this is why I'm struggling to find anything!

Comment: A bit more Googling reveals what I'm actually after is "parts of speech" - Moby thesaurus seems to have this covered.

Comment: You're looking for something like a dictionary. What went wrong when you tried using a dictionary? (Knowing why a dictionary is insufficient for your needs may help us zero in on exactly what you need.)

Comment: If you look at a dictionary, an entry fro a word should give its extensions with suffixes (most likely not prefixes). But maybe that's not so easy to see. It's a little more obvious if you just look at a plain online wordlist (like /usr/share/dict/words).

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for a [vocabulary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vocabulary?searchDictCode=all) (which is practically a dictionary without meanings).

Since you are looking for a database, a [lexical database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_database) may help. Take a look at [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/).